# PHP, cant locate password through email

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email

I was doing a php exercise where I put an email, and it would run throught the DB and show me the password that belongs to that email. But everytime I tried, even tho the email was registered it would say the email doesn't exist.
Here it is the page where it will run:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "xxxxxxxx");

if ($conn) {
  echo 'conected';
} else {
  echo 'not conected ';
}
echo '<p>';

$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
$password = mysql_query("SELECT senha FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
    if ('$email'=='$emailcheck') {
        echo "$password";
    }else {
echo "Email does not exist";
}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
 <form action="password.php" method="post"  >     
    Email: <br />  <input type="text" name="email"  /> <br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit"/> 
    </form>
```

Sorry from my bad english, and notice that when it says 'senha', it is password in portuguese.

Comment: After a query unless you do fetch data (with mysql_fetch_row or similar) you will eventually see Resource #X (x = number). However it will be a good practice for you to leave mysql_* that are deprecated command and use mysqli_* or pdo libraries ^^

Comment: [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) accepts 3 parameters, the 4th is for *If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments, no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of the already opened link will be returned. The new_link parameter modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored. The client_flags parameter can be a combination of the following constants:*

Comment: Your code will fail in many ways. That's not how you check if something matches a row in a DB; use `mysql_num_rows()`.

Comment: You don't have to wrap variables with quotes.even if you did, you have to use double quotes.I'm referring to your `if` clause.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're learning from a tutorial, that material is **dangerously out of date**. `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job for you but check my notes!

For your connection:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("coms11g") or die(mysql_error()); //this is the name of database
```

And to fetch

```
$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]) . "'");
$res = mysql_query($emailcheck);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if ($row) {
    echo "The password is " . $row["senha"];
} else {
    echo "Email does not exist";
}
```

**NOTE:**

- Do not use mysql functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.
- Always escape your variables cames from outside in your query, to avoid sql injection, or use prepared statements.

Comment: Instead of being a `mysql_query` enabler, it might be better to present this as `mysqli` or PDO as well to encourage people to switch. The contrast is usually striking as PDO is a lot more concise.

Comment: You are right man, but as I see, the OP has a really poor skill in this, he does not know the basics, so I do not want to confuse him with mysqli or PDO first. If he got the point, what does it mean fetch and others, then I hope, he will change to one of the most current layer.

Comment: To be brutally honest, if someone is "confused" by PDO, they really should not be writing SQL interfacing code at all. The risk of a mistake is staggeringly high. Secondly, PDO is actually easier to write than `mysql_query` based code because the placeholders significantly clean things up and with exceptions turned on you do not need to pay attention to every potential error condition.

Comment: As I sad to you, you are right. But if you think about, how many good PHP books (old ones, eg. Learn PHP in 24 hours) gives example with mysql functions. As you see, OP has no idea, what is resource, what should be compared, etc... So I tried to point him with some basics. IF at this point I rewrite it to PDO for example, and he has not enabled that extension, or not compiled that in PHP, then he will totally lost, and facing other problems. This is why I mentioned it in my NOTE section.

Comment: All those books should be burned or reduced to holding up monitors. No matter how good they were, they're damaging now. What you've done here is enabled someone to create more legacy code that *must* be replaced as `mysql_query` is being removed in future versions of PHP. If PDO is a problem now, not having that interface at all after upgrading PHP will be a much bigger deal later.